# Grails 2.4.3 does not work on mac os x

Tags: macos, grails, grails-2.4, gvm

I am using grails installation on mac os x v.10.9.5.
I used to have grails 2.4.2 installation and it was working fine.
As I tried to install 2.4.3 version (both through gvm and manually, by unpacking archive and setting PATH and GRAILS_HOME variables), the installation seems to be ok, but when running "grails" command from terminal it had no effect, just the behaviour similar to "clear" terminal command. No output or error message was provided.

Does anyone have ideas what could be wrong with environment or installation? Or at least where can I find logs from running "grails" command?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: If you switch back to 2.4.2 with gvm does everthing work? If so try unintalling and reinstalling 2.4.3 in gvm

Comment: I have 2.4.3 working on mac osx myself

Comment: What does `which grails` do for you?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, `which grails` points to gvm grails installation:
`admin$ which grails
/Users/admin/.gvm/grails/current/bin/grails`.

@JeffBeck, yes, old 2.4.2 installation works (it was not a gvm installation). Reinstalling 2.4.3 in gvm, as well as reinstalling gvm did not have any effect.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that the `grails` command would behave like the `clear` command.  If I had the system in front of me it would be a 15 second mission to fix it but without that it is hard to say what is going wrong.  I am sorry that I can't help.

Comment: Try installing grails using the gvmtool  http://gvmtool.net/  , its the only way to fly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find your grails installation, then check its shell wrapper at `bin/grails`. Suppose it contains the following lines :

```
#!/bin/sh
trap "reset" EXIT
trap "reset" INT
trap "reset" TERM

DIRNAME=`dirname "$0"`
. "$DIRNAME/startGrails"

startGrails org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner "$@"
```

Use your favourite text editor to edit the file, add `#` in front of the `trap`s to comment those lines out.

```
#trap "reset" EXIT
#trap "reset" INT
#trap "reset" TERM
```

Then execute any grails commands like `grails -version`, check the console output to find the real reason that grails did not run. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks!  It's almost impossible to troubleshoot without actually seeing what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and in my case the error was due to $JAVA_HOME environment variable. For grails to execute properly java is a prerequisite. Therefore you should check whether you have added java to your class path before executing grails.

To verify this you should run, `java -version` before grails commands such as `grails -version`